# Map Reduce word count program gives "class not found exception"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, word-count

My hadoop version is : **2.8.1**

I am trying to run the mapreduce example which is in [Apache Hadoop 2.8.0](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

WordCount source code is as below.(same as given in the Apache Hadoop 2.8.0 example)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
private Text word = new Text();

public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, 
  InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
   }
  }
}

public static class IntSumReducer
   extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                   Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  int sum = 0;
  for (IntWritable val : values) {
    sum += val.get();
  }
  result.set(sum);
  context.write(key, result);
 }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
  job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
  job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
  job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
  job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
  FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
  System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
}
```

I created a WordCount.java file by inserting the above code. 
Then I compiled it.

```
javac -cp $HADOOP_CLASSPATH /sharedFiles/WordCount.java
```

Then I combined WordCount*.classes to create a wc.jar file.

```
jar cf /sharedFiles/wc.jar /sharedFiles/WordCount*.class
```

Inside the sharedFiles folder, files look as below.

```
ls /sharedFiles
history  wc.jar  WordCount.class  
WordCount$IntSumReducer.class        
WordCount.java    WordCount$TokenizerMapper.class
```

Then I tried to run the mapreduce command.

```
hadoop jar /sharedFiles/wc.jar wordcount /sharedFiles/history /sharedFiles /output
```

It throws me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wordcount
```

I have noticed that the driver class "wordcount" is not created in the respective folder. Is there anything I can do to create that class? In the tutorial, they haven't mentioned any additional step to create that file.

Thank you.

Comment: When you created the JAR, did it think that the sharedFiles folder was a package? Did you try `sharedFiles.WordCount`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, it worked. Along with that, package name needed to be added to the WordCount,java file as well. I don't understand why it is needed though, because in the command line, we specify the complete path of the WordCount.java. 

However it did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Yash, could you please verify your command. I think you written class name in small case letter, While running Hadoop jar command.

```
hadoop jar /sharedFiles/wc.jar WordCount /sharedFiles/history  /sharedFiles /output
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I changed it and still getting the error.                                              hadoop jar /sharedFiles/wc.jar WordCount /sharedFiles/history /sharedFiles/output
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount

Comment: Also could you please check tar -tf WC.jar command. It will show if required classes are generated properly or not.